# Mvc not format a href link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have mvc project. On controller I format link next way:

```
 user.ShortBiography = user.LongBiography.Substring(0, 100) + "... <a href=\"#\">Read more</a>";
```

On Views the HTML format next way:

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(score => item.ShortBiography)</p>
```

When I open site on browser, I see this result:

```
Some text ... <a href="#">Read more</a>
```

So.MVC doesn't format link. I see only text with tags. So. How it's fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either make ShortBiography a HtmlString or you will need to do this:

```
@Html.Raw(item.ShortBiography)
```

I have also used helpers which convert string to HtmlString

```
@Html.DisplayFor(score => item.ShortBiography.ToHtmlString())
```